# Why do $x - ct = 0$ and $x' - ct' = 0$ imply that $(x - ct) = \lambda (x' - ct')$ in special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

From the book, [Relativity: The Special and General Theory](https://www.ibiblio.org/ebooks/Einstein/Einstein_Relativity.pdf) (PDF) by Albert Einstein - Appendix 1:

> A light-signal, which is proceeding along the positive axis of $x$, is  transmitted according to the equation $$ x = ct $$ or $$ x - ct = 0. \hspace{2em}(1)$$ Since the same light-signal has to be transmitted relative to $K'$ with the velocity $c$, the propagation relative to the system $K'$ will be represented by the analogous formula $$ x' - ct' = 0. \hspace{2em}(2)$$ Those space-time points (events) which satisfy $\text{(1)}$ must also satisfy $\text{(2)}$. Obviously this will be the case when the relation $$ (x' - ct') = \lambda (x - ct) \hspace{2em} (3) $$ is fulfiled in general, where $ \lambda $ indicates a constant; for, according to $\text{(3)}$, the disappearance of $(x - ct)$ involves the disappearance of $(x' - ct')$.

Can someone explain why we must conclude the equation (3) from equations (1) and (2)? I am unable to see why we need to introduce the constant $\lambda$.

If $ x - ct = 0 $ and $ x' - ct' = 0 $, then I get $ x - ct = x' - ct' = 0 $. I see no need for a constant $ \lambda $. Can someone explain to me why must I add a constant $ \lambda $ in equation (3).

Comment: "does $a=0$ and $b=0$ imply $a=cb$?" well, yes, most definitely, and very tautologically.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I guess I am having difficulty understanding why I would introduce such a constant in my analysis and why would I even conclude that this constant would have a single well-defined value.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform the question is deeper than it seems. Why $a=cb$ and not $a=b^3$? Even more, we're not talking about $a=b=0$, but functions. f(x)=0 and g(x)=0 does not neccesarily mean they are proportional

Comment: @LoneLearner It is hard to tell why the author chooses to introduce the constant; we have to read the rest of the chapter. But everything they have said so far is, strictly speaking, true, if in a very tautological way. Why they write what they write cannot be deduced from the information you have provided. The key point in the argument, the point that is really confusing you, should come next, in the following paragraphs.

Comment: @Lone Your $x - ct = x' - ct' = 0$ is basically the same as eqn (3), except you're implicitly setting $\lambda=1$. It's better to not make such premature assumptions. ;)

Comment: @FGSUZ Both $a=cb$ and $a=b^3$ are correct. I am not claiming that $a=bc$ is useful; only that, given the information we have, this equation is most definitely correct, in a very trivial way. I am complaining that OP has not presented the whole argument, but only a small excerpt, which is not enough to really clarify what's going on. [And, for the record, two identically vanishing functions are most definitely proportional, so I'm not sure what you mean in your last sentence...]

Comment: Does the book not say more about this constant?

Comment: I just looked. Yes, it does. I would suggest to keep reading :)

Comment: They assume that the transformation is linear for simplicity, and it happens to work! They could have chosen any other function that satisfy 1 and 2

Answer (score 3):

Eq. (3) is a consequence of the symmetry imposed by the principle of relativity.
I hope my proof is what you are looking for.

First of all, we assume $(x'-ct')$ can be expressed as a function of 
$(x- ct)$,

$$x' - ct' = \Phi(x-ct) \quad ,$$

with $\Phi$ being at least invertible and $C^1$.

***Side remark** : From the technical point of view this follows from the fact that space-time is a differentiable topological manifold with a smooth atlas, however we don't need so much rigour here.*

The systems $K$ and $K'$ are equivalent in all respects. 
Therefore the inverse function must have the same functional form up to a constant
$$x - ct = \Phi^{-1}(x' - ct') = \alpha \, \Phi(x'- ct')
\qquad \quad (*)$$

***Note 1** : Equivalence doesn't mean triviality though.
We must have $\Phi(0)=0$
(the speed of light is the same for all inertial observers), 
and the functional form is the same "up to a constant" because a change in the units of measure doesn't spoil the physical equivalence.*

***Note 2** : $\alpha=0$ has no physical meaning. 
If it was true, 
$K$ would see any particle moving at the speed of light, 
even if for $K'$ the latter was slower.*

Eq. $(*)$ is true only if $\Phi$ is a linear function.
Let's see why.

Consider a value $a$ and map it to $b=\Phi(a)$. 
As discussed above one has:
$$a = \Phi^{-1}(b) = \alpha \, \Phi(b) = \alpha (\Phi \circ \Phi) \, (a)$$
From the arbitrariness of $a$ we conclude that $\alpha (\Phi \circ \Phi)$ is the identity operator. Hence we have:
$$\Phi\left(\frac{a}{\alpha}\right) = 
\Phi \circ \Phi \, (b) = 
\frac{1}{\alpha} b = 
\frac{1}{\alpha} \Phi(a) 
$$

Calling $\beta = 1/\alpha$:
$$\Phi(\beta \, a) = \beta \, \Phi(a)$$
In other words $\Phi$ is a homogeneous function of degree $1$.

From the Euler's theorem of homogeneous functions:
$$\Phi(a) = a \, \frac{d}{da} \Phi (a) $$
Deriving with respect to $a$ we get:
$$ a \frac{d^2}{da^2} \Phi (a) = 0 
\quad \rightarrow \quad
\Phi(a) = \lambda a  + \nu
\quad \text{for } a \neq 0
$$
However the invariance of the speed of light sets $\Phi(0)=0$, 
so we get the solution (now valid $\forall \, a$):
$$\Phi(a) = \lambda \, a$$

Back to our problem,
$$x' - ct' = \lambda (x - ct) \quad .$$

Answer (score 1):

Equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ specify two trajectories in frames $K$ and $K'$ respectively. Since they are trajectories, $x$ and $t$ here are obviously not independent, and their relationship is specified by eq. $(1)$. Similarly $x'$ and $t'$ are related by eq. $(2)$. So these two equations specify two subsets of spacetime, the first one seen through $K$ and the second one through $K'$. Constancy of the speed of light requires these two sets to be the same.

Our goal, on the other hand, is finding a transformation $(x, t) \rightarrow (x', t')$ that transforms *any* couple $(x, t)$ in $K$ into a couple $(x', t')$ in $K'$. *Any* couple, not only those satisfying $(1)$. The requirement of constancy of the speed of light imposes that when this transformation is applied to eq. $(1)$, it has to become eq. $(2)$.

Einstein here is simply saying that if we impose the **much stronger** requirement that eq. $(3)$ is satisfied by **every** couple $(x, t)$ with its transformed $(x', t')$, then eq. $(1)$ gets obviously transformed into eq. $(2)$.

I want to stress here that $(3)$ **is not** a tautological consequence of $(1)$ and $(2)$ with an added superfluous constant: indeed, $(1)$ and $(2)$ only specify two sets of spacetime points in frames $K$ and $K'$ respectively, while $(3)$ is a relation that Einstein is imposing on **every** spacetime point, also those not belonging to sets $(1)$ and $(2)$ (notice that, after eq. $(3)$, he writes that it is imposed to be "fulfilled *in general*").

Now you could ask: But why should we use specifically requirement $(3)$, and not one of the infinitely many others that would equally ensure that $(1)$ gets transformed into $(2)$? Well, see @momi94's answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

All the book is saying (at this stage) is that this is obviously *a* solution.  There is no suggestion at this stage that it is the only solution.

Equally obviously $(x-ct) = λ(x'-ct')^n$ is also a solution for any non-zero value of λ and any non-zero value of n.  Many other solutions are also available.

Any addition of two or more different left or right hand sides is also a solution, and any multiplication of two or more solutions is also a solution.

As advised above, I too suggest you read on, remembering the limit of the logic.